# Maximize the minimal distance to cat

Tags: charts

You are given a 2-d matrix. Cells are either Land ('L') or Water ('W'). You can walk on land but not walk on water. One of the land cell has cat on it. You are given start and end cells.
Find a path from src to tgt whose minimum distance to the cat is maximum among all possible paths.